# Session is coming null in handler in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, handler

I want to access session in handler for that i am inheriting "IRequireSessionState" Class. but while evaluating the session it is coming null, but on the web page it has value. i dont know why this is happening my code of handler is:

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
String Name = Common.GetSessionValue("UserId").ToString() ;
// my code.........
```

Here is my common method to Get Session's value

```
 public static Guid GetSessionValue(string SessionName)
    {
        Guid returnvalue = Guid.Empty;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionName] != null)
        {
            returnvalue = new Guid(HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionName].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
        return returnvalue;
    }
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this by Exposing the value to the outside world http://forums.asp.net/t/1506625.aspx/1 and then trying to fetch the value in handler using

```
context.Request.Form["returnvalue"];
```

You can see the exposed value in firebug AddOn in Mozilla